# Make image overlap the span text

Tags: html, css

When you `hover` over `HERE`, then the `image` should be centered. And second problem is that `HERE` text should disappear (overlapped) because only the `image` should show. How to make these two problems work?

```css
.eee span {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size:2em;
}

.ggg {
 color: yellow;
 background: red;
}

.hhh {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: black;
}

.hhh:hover {
 background-color: green;
 background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/60x60);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="eee"><div class="fff"><span class="ggg">?</span> 
<span class="hhh">HERE</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-position:center` to center the image and `color: rgba()` to hide the text

```css
.eee span {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size:2em;
}

.ggg {
 color: yellow;
 background: red;
}

.hhh {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: black;
}

.hhh:hover {
 background-color: green;
 background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/60x60);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="eee"><div class="fff"><span class="ggg">?</span> 
    <span class="hhh">HERE</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.eee span {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size:2em;
}

.ggg {
 color: yellow;
 background: red;
}

.hhh {
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: black;
}

.hhh:hover {
 background-color: green;
 background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/60x60);
 text-align: center;
 background-position:center;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="eee"><div class="fff"><span class="ggg">?</span> 
<span class="hhh">HERE</span>
</div>
</div>
```